# Problems accessing a Swift dictionary variable inside of a function in my ViewController Class

Tags: ios, dictionary, swift, uiviewcontroller

Initialized my ViewController Class like so:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        // Create a dict of images for use with the UIView menu tab
        var imageDict = [String:UIImage]()
        imageDict["hudson_terrace"] = UIImage(named: "hudson_terrace")
        imageDict["sky_room"] = UIImage(named: "sky_room")
        imageDict["rivington"] = UIImage(named: "rivington")
        imageDict["highline_ballroom"] = UIImage(named: "highline_ballroom")
        imageDict["gansevoort_park_redroom"] = UIImage(named: "gansevoort_park_redroom")
        imageDict["gansevoort_park_rooftop"] = UIImage(named: "gansevoort_park_rooftop")
        imageDict["evr"] = UIImage(named: "evr")

    }
```

Wrote this function later on in the class...

```
    func addImageViews () {

        // loop through imageDict and add all the images as UIView subviews of menuScrollView
        for (venue_name, image) in self.imageDict {

        }
    }
```

and I'm getting the error "ViewController" does not have a member named "imageDict".

Not sure why imageDict is not available to me inside of the function. Can anybody suggest a better place to put the dict and how to access it?

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring `imageDict` as a variable local to the `init` initializer, so it exists only in that context. As soon as the function (initializer) exits, the variable is deallocated, and cannot be referenced outside of that context.

In order to reference it from any method of the class, you should declare it as a property of the class:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var imageDict = [String:UIImage]()

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        // Create a dict of images for use with the UIView menu tab
        imageDict["hudson_terrace"] = UIImage(named: "hudson_terrace")
        imageDict["sky_room"] = UIImage(named: "sky_room")
        imageDict["rivington"] = UIImage(named: "rivington")
        imageDict["highline_ballroom"] = UIImage(named: "highline_ballroom")
        imageDict["gansevoort_park_redroom"] = UIImage(named: "gansevoort_park_redroom")
        imageDict["gansevoort_park_rooftop"] = UIImage(named: "gansevoort_park_rooftop")
        imageDict["evr"] = UIImage(named: "evr")
    }
```

By doing so, the property is available to any instance method of the class.